# OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long

Tags: python-3.x

My output here:

> OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long:
>   "/media/than/3E7019A6701965C5//nhandt_MaskRCNN_Nouth/['1.JPG',
>   '18-10.JPG', '18-11.JPG', '18-12.JPG', '18-13.JPG', '18-14.JPG',
>   '18-15.JPG', '18-16.JPG', '18-17.JPG', '18-18.JPG', '18-19.JPG',
>   '18-2.JPG', '18-20.JPG', '18-21.JPG', '18-22.JPG', '18-23.JPG',
>   '18-24.JPG', '18-25.JPG', '18-26.JPG', '18-3.JPG', '18-4.JPG',
>   '18-5.JPG', '18-6.JPG', '18-7.JPG', '18-8.JPG', '18-9.JPG'].jpg"

The code in python

```
font = ImageFont.truetype('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMono.ttf', 28, encoding="unic" )
draw.text((x1, y1), "%s %f" % (label, score), (255, 255, 255), font)
```

How can I fix it

Comment: It looks like you are trying to save a file with a string representation of an array as the file name.  You can fix this by not saving the file with a string representation of an array as the filename.

Comment: Thanks you, I have fixed it.

Comment: Please edit your question as it is very hard to understand what you are asking. Also, if you answered your own question (you mentioned you have fixed your code) - then post your answer in order to help others who might encounter your own issue. Good luck!